# Complication on Apple Watch not showing my information

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch, apple-watch-complication

I'm faced with a problem with complications on Apple Watch.

I'm trying to display images and some texts on a complication. I can select the complication on the Clock interface but it shows nothing that the app title and two lines full of "-" character.

The complication should show my information instead, but I don't see what is wrong in my code

Here is the code:

```
func getLocalizableSampleTemplate(for complication: CLKComplication, withHandler handler: @escaping (CLKComplicationTemplate?) -> Void) {
    // This method will be called once per supported complication, and the results will be cached
    handler(nil)
    var template: CLKComplicationTemplateModularLargeColumns?
    switch complication.family {
    case .modularSmall:
        template = nil
    case .modularLarge:
        let modularLargeTemplate =
            CLKComplicationTemplateModularLargeColumns()
        modularLargeTemplate.row1ImageProvider =
            CLKImageProvider(onePieceImage: UIImage(named: "GreenUser")!)
        modularLargeTemplate.row2ImageProvider =
            CLKImageProvider(onePieceImage: UIImage(named: "GreenUser")!)
        modularLargeTemplate.row3ImageProvider =
            CLKImageProvider(onePieceImage: UIImage(named: "GreenUser")!)

        modularLargeTemplate.row1Column1TextProvider = CLKSimpleTextProvider(text: "User: ")
        modularLargeTemplate.row1Column2TextProvider = CLKSimpleTextProvider(text: "ok")

        modularLargeTemplate.row2Column1TextProvider = CLKSimpleTextProvider(text: "Car: ")
        modularLargeTemplate.row2Column2TextProvider = CLKSimpleTextProvider(text: "ok")

        modularLargeTemplate.row3Column1TextProvider = CLKSimpleTextProvider(text: "Environment: ")
        modularLargeTemplate.row3Column2TextProvider = CLKSimpleTextProvider(text: "ok")

        template = modularLargeTemplate
    case .utilitarianSmall:
        template = nil
    case .utilitarianLarge:
        template = nil
    case .circularSmall:
        template = nil
    default:
        template = nil
    }
    handler(template)

}
```

If I place a breakpoint in the middle of the code, the debugger trigger it, so it executes this code. However nothing is displayed like I want.

Can you find what is wrong/missing?

Comment: Why are you calling `handler(nil)` in the beginning??? Your whole function is not executed, it returns a `nil` closure straight away.

Comment: @DávidPásztor I tried to remove that line, but the result is still the same

Comment: Did you actually check whether your function is called and whether `template` is `nil` or not when it is called?

Comment: Yes I checked, the function is called and template is not nil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just the template, you need to take care of `getCurrentTimelineEntry`, the simplest would be just to return the same entry as template (see below).
And as other mentioned in comments, you need to delete `handler(nil)` in your code as well.

```
func getCurrentTimelineEntry(for complication: CLKComplication, withHandler handler: @escaping (CLKComplicationTimelineEntry?) -> Void) {
        getLocalizableSampleTemplate(for: complication) {template in
            guard let template = template else {
                handler(nil)
                return
            }
            handler(CLKComplicationTimelineEntry(date: Date(), complicationTemplate: template))
        }
    }
```

Comment: Brotha, you just saved me loads of time.  Completely wasn't understanding the timeline stuff and wasted 2 days trying to figure out why i couldn't show a simple image.  Thanks!